# After converting Adobe Garamond Pro with autoinst, only f_i and f_l ligatures available in pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, otftotfm

I need to use Adobe Garamond in my document and therefore acquired the font package from https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/garamond?tab=familyPackages to get access to the `OTF` files. As with other fonts before, I converted it with `autoinst`, namely my call looked like this:

```
autoinst -serif -target=".\testtexmf\" -vendor="Adobe" -typeface="GaramondPro" AGaramondPro-Bold.otf AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.otf AGaramondPro-Italic.otf AGaramondPro-Regular.otf AGaramondPro-Semibold.otf AGaramondPro-SemiboldItalic.otf
```

This created all necessary files and I am able to use them in PdfLaTeX by including my created package.

Nevertheless I have issues with all ligatures except `f_i` and `f_l`, they are not available in PdfLaTeX. But they are available in the font, as can be seen at https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/garamond?tab=glyphs and I checked this with FontForge, DP Font Viewer and also in LibreOffice Writer.

Also `otfinfo -g AGaramondPro-Regular.otf` reports the following glyphs:

```
f_f
f_i
f_l
twodotenleader
onedotenleader
f_f_i
f_f_l
```

and when using the `-manual` option for `autoinst`, I also see the `--ligkern="f i =: fi" --ligkern="f l =: fl" --ligkern="f f =: ff" --ligkern="ff i =: ffi" --ligkern="ff l =: ffl"` section in the calls, so my understanding is, everything should be right, but it isn't.

Do you have any ideas what I am missing to get the `ff`, `ffi` and `ffl` ligatures in my documents?

---

### Additional information after more trial & error

I wanted to make sure, that `autoinst` and `otftotfm` are able to access the ligatures and I think this leads to the right direction. So what did I do: I replaced the following lines in the `fontools_ly1.enc` and `fontools_t1.enc`:

```
/ff
/fi
/fl
/ffi
/ffl
```

with

```
/uniFB00
/uniFB01
/uniFB02
/uniFB03
/uniFB04
```

Now I can see the characters in the font table:

[image]

But in the text, the ligatures are not used, probably because TeX doesn't know, what the unicodes are for:

[image]

So it seems the problem is, `otftotfm` cannot access the glyphs by saying `/ff` in the `*.enc` files. Do you have an idea, how I can circumvent this?

### Trying out @Ulrike Fischer proposal

I followed the advice of @Ulrike Fischer. So I modified the last line of the encoding file, which now reads:

```
% UNICODING ff =: uniFB00; fi =: uniFB01; fl =: uniFB02; ffi =: uniFB03; ffl =: uniFB04;
```

The ligatures are now all part of the ejected font tables, but LaTeX is still not using them in regular text. Is there an additional step to make it work?

Comment: Unless your publisher demands you use PDFTeX, by far the simplest and best solution is to use the OTF font with `fontspec`.

Comment: If you must go back to obsolete technology: The `-ligatures` option should be the default, and so should the OT!, T1, LY1 and TS1 encodings. You might try setting up your `.sty` file to use the T1 encoding instead of LY1?

Comment: `\tracinglostchars=2` in your document might help diagnose the error, for example by telling you what font and encoding the TeX engine is trying to find the ligature in.

Comment: what do mean by "the ligatures are not available"? Do you get missing glyphs or do you get the normal glyphs but only without ligature?

Comment: @Davislor: pdfTeX is not a requirement, so using fontspec might be acceptable, however I am in the publishing phase and hence have to see, what side effects are caused. The `T1` or `LY1` doesn't change anything, ligatures didn't make it into any of these encodings.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: What I mean is, that the glyph is not available when outputting all glyphs/symbols of the font, e.g. by `\fonttable{AGaramondPro-Regular-lf-ly1}`. This font table only has fi in slot 28 and fl in slot 29. No other glyphs with ligatures are there. So no I am not getting missing glyphs, there is ff printed, jsut not as a ligature.

Comment: I updated the question with more information. It seems the problem is that otftotfm cannot access the glyphs by `/ff` but only with `/uniFB00`. Any ideas for this problem?

Comment: you will probably have to tell otftotfm that the ligatures have unusual names in your font, see UNICODING in the otftotfm documentation, and then rebuild the font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I followed you advice and added `% UNICODING ff =: uniFB00; fi =: uniFB01; fl =: uniFB02; ffi =: uniFB03; ffl =: uniFB04;` to my encoding file. Ligatures are now all converted and in the font table, but LaTeX is still not using them to replace ff and others.

Comment: well as the documentation says, you can also add LIGKERN instructions. And you will perhaps have to use --noligatures with autoinst (but I have no idea in which order the various options are handled).

Comment: Information about ligatures are in `.tfm` file; one option is convert it to `.pl` file using `tftopl`, then you can manually set ligatures in some text editor, then switch it back to `.tfm` using `pltotf`.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your help. I have no idea what happened, but after several attempts, I went back to CTAN to download the latest `autoinst.pl` and `*.enc` files and ran the script again and now it works out of the box without any adjustments. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TobiBS Huh. Auto-updating is a good idea.

Comment: Well before I used the latest version of all tools that come with the latest `MikTeX`, but I wanted to debug a bit more to see what `autoinst` does and then went back to CTAN to get the raw `perl` script. In the end it now also works with the original `autoinst` so I don't really know, what did the trick.